# How can i add the entity to user object in constructor in symfony2 Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the `user` object who has manytomany relation with `Group` entity.

But i want that by default the user should  be added to Group `Group_User` which has id=4 in database.

Now how can i add that in User constructor

How can use query in Entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass what you want in your User constructor. You'll have to pass it from your controller (where your queryManger is available).

In your controller:

```
$group_user = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository("Bundle:Entity")->find(4);
$user = new User($group_user);
```

In your construct:

```
public function __construct(Group $group_user)
{
    $this->$group = $group_user;
}
```

When you'll persist your user entity in the controller, the user and it's group relation will be directly saved.

Comment: But how will i get that group with id=4 in the constructor. youmean to say that i have to do in controller. i was looking if i can do that in Entity itself

Comment: It's a bad idea IMO to manipulate EntityMangager in an Entity. An Entity should be agnostic of the EM and just work with others entities. I use this in my project, an object is related to a pricing plan, I pass the pricing plan object through the constructor